# VBA code to bring over background color of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out if there is code out there to copy over the background color of a cell.  Like for instance cell a1 had a background color of white but i decided I wanted to highlight that cell to yellow, is it possible just to bring over that color formatting with vba code?

Comment: Try `Range.Interior.Color = RGB(r, g, b)`.  `r`, `g` and `b` are integers in the range 0 to 255.  There are colour charts on the web that will give you the red, green and blue values for a wide range of colours.  Yellow is `RGB(255, 255, 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("A1").Style = "Neutral" 'select whatever cell you want to change
    'this style is kinda yellow
    Range("A2").Style = "Accent6" 'select whatever cell you want to change
    'this style is orange
    'you will have to use whatever accent you want
End Sub
```

You'll have to adapt it a little for your use. Let me know if this helps!

Just tried something else. This one actually changes the fill color, not just the style.

```
Range("A3").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
```